# Scala: how to use a Java callback API

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous

Assume you are using a 3rd party Java API which streams data, asynchronously, via a callback.  **What (fundamental) design options do we have if we use such an API in Scala?**  I am new to the language.  Here's what I thought of:

1. Provide a Scala function from the wild to use as the callback (for example create some `object` which contains the callback function)
2. We can optionally have this object send a message to an Akka actor (pass the data along).  It this way we can fuel an actor system with input data.
3. Data packaging-- a case class... but remember the data originate from a Java function.  Is our only option for the Scala callback to receive the raw data using multiple arguments (strings, ints, doubles) before packing in a case class instance?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: This particular software base is still pure Java, where I have an interface that specifies a callback function.  Then, whenever I need a class that uses this data, I implement the interface.  To sign up for for data, I pass the class reference to a middleman which sends out the data as it comes in from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Provide a Scala function from the wild to use as the callback (for example create some object which contains the callback function)

Yes. You should use Scala 2.12, there the Scala Functions are compiled to Java SAMs and you can just stick them into the Java API.

> 2. We can optionally have this object send a message to an Akka actor (pass the data along). It this way we can fuel an actor system with
>      input data.

Yes, you could. That's not alternative to 1, it's something you would do within the function you mention in 1.

> 3. Data packaging-- a case class... but remember the data originate from a Java function. Is our only option for the Scala callback to
>      receive the raw data using multiple arguments (strings, ints, doubles)
>      before packing in a case class instance?

Not sure I understand. You want to put in a function that expects a different type than what is provided? As in, your API expects a callback handler that takes 3 parameters, and instead you'd like to provide one that takes one, a case class? I have a feeling that's not going to work. I'd rather just instantiate the case class within the function.

Comment: Clarifying 1&3.  Suppose the Java API needs `callback(int, string, double)`.  So you are saying, I can provide a Scala function with that prototype and then instantiate a case class.  I was thinking I HAD to provide a Java callback, which in turn could call my Scala callback.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm saying. I'm saying if a Java Lambda is expected, you can put in a Scala 2.12 Function (I was assuming you provide a lambda as the callback function). Does that make sense? Maybe you could provide a code snippet, or a public Java API that can serve as example, to make sure I don't misunderstand. Also, a Scala class can implement a Java interface - if we're not talking Lambdas, but some arbitrary Java interface that prescribes certain functions, you can implement that in Scala as well.